# How to stack columns on excel

Tags: excel, vba, stack

I have a spreadsheet of data that is in the current format of:

```
A1, A2, A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3
```

Im trying to stack the data so that it follows this format:

```
A1, A2, A3,
B1, B2, B3
C1, C2, C3
```

This is so i can import into some software in the correct format.

I have found the following code online which does indeed stack data, however it stacks every column, whereas i need it to stack every third column and wondered if any one could just modify this macro to do so?

Thanks in advance.

```
Option Explicit


Sub Stack_cols()


On Error GoTo Stack_cols_Error

Dim lNoofRows As Long, lNoofCols As Long
Dim lLoopCounter As Long, lCountRows As Long
Dim sNewShtName As String
Dim shtOrg As Worksheet, shtNew As Worksheet

'Turn off the screen update to make macro run faster
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Ask for a new sheet name, if not provided use newsht
sNewShtName = InputBox("Enter the new worksheet name", "Enter name", "newsht")
'Set a sheet variable for the sheet where the data resides
Set shtOrg = ActiveSheet
'Add a new worksheet, rename it and set it to a variable
If Not SheetExists(sNewShtName) Then
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = sNewShtName
    Set shtNew = Worksheets(sNewShtName)
Else
    MsgBox "Worksheet name exists. Try again", vbInformation, "Sheet Exists"
    Exit Sub
End If

With shtOrg
    'Get the last column number
    'Replace .Range("IV1") with .Range("XFD1") for Excel 2007
    lNoofCols = .Range("IV1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Start a loop to copy and paste data from the first column to the last column
    For lLoopCounter = 1 To lNoofCols
    'Count the number of rows in the looping column
        'Replace .Cells(65536, lLoopCounter) with .Cells(1048576, lLoopCounter) for Excel 2007
        lNoofRows = .Cells(65536, lLoopCounter).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(1, lLoopCounter), .Cells(lNoofRows, lLoopCounter)).Copy Destination:=shtNew.Range(shtNew.Cells(lCountRows + 1, 1), shtNew.Cells(lCountRows + lNoofRows, 1))
        'count the number of rows in the new worksheet
        lCountRows = lCountRows + lNoofRows
    Next lLoopCounter
End With

On Error GoTo 0
SmoothExit_Stack_cols:
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Exit Sub

Stack_cols_Error:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in Sub:Stack_cols"
    Resume SmoothExit_Stack_cols
End Sub
'Check if a worksheet exists or not
Public Function SheetExists(sShtName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next


Dim wsSheet As Worksheet, bResult As Boolean
bResult = False
Set wsSheet = Sheets(sShtName)

On Error GoTo 0
If Not wsSheet Is Nothing Then
    bResult = True
End If
SheetExists = bResult
End Function
```

EDIT.

This is the data I am trying to Stack.[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48RfQ.png)

This is how I want it too look [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mywa2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted seems overly complicated for what you're trying to achieve, try this:

```
Sub stackColumns()

Dim lngRow As Long, lngCol As Long, i As Long
lngRow = 1
lngCol = 0

For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    ActiveSheet.Cells(lngRow, lngCol + 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value
    If lngRow > 1 Then ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Clear
    lngCol = (lngCol + 1) Mod 3
    If lngCol = 0 Then lngRow = lngRow + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

This assumes your data starts in cell A1.

EDIT: To fit your actual dataset use this (even shorter) version:

```
Sub stackColumns()

Dim i As Long

With ActiveSheet
    For i = 4 To .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Step 3
        .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, i + 2).End(xlUp).Row, i + 2)).Cut _
        Destination:=.Range("A" & .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work the best. I may have not been as descriptive as possible.

Comment: No, sorry i was trying to add a screenshot but cant quite figure out. Is there a way to add screenshots on comments so I can show you better?

Comment: No, you need to add the screenshot as an edit to your question.

Comment: I updated my answer, this will do exactly what you're looking for. If this solved your problem please consider upvoting and marking the answer as accepted, so others may find it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim lc As Long, x As Long, y As Long
Dim arr As Variant

With Sheet1 'Change accordingly
    lc = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    arr = .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, lc)
    .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, lc).Clear
    y = 1
    For x = 1 To lc Step 3
        .Cells(y, 1).Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(arr(1, x), arr(1, x + 1), arr(1, x + 2))
        y = y + 1
    Next x
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: i get this error when running the code which highlights

  .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, lc).Clear

and says 'cannot change part of a merged cell' - although no merge cells are in the worksheet

Comment: @MacauleyPowell, the error says otherwise. Mergedcells are a nightmare and I recommend to get rid of them asap. Running this code for me went just fine as the added screenshots show.

Comment: Hi, i can assure you there are no merge columns, it is a brand new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep it simple, so here is another example...

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3") 'change sheet as needed

x = 1
y = 2

    With ws
        For x = 1 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column Step 3
            .Cells(1, x).Resize(, 3).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(y, 1)
            y = y + 1
        Next x

        .Cells(1, 4).Resize(, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column).Clear
    End With
```